# htaccess Rewrite for mobile websites

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mobile

I apologize for the stupid question.

I have my website setup where `evanstoddard.me/about` ends up being `evanstoddard.me/index.php?cmd=about`.  This works great for the desktop website but I now want it to work for the mobile site as well.

I have a script setup to detect if the browser is a mobile website so I can just as easily have the desktop site pass that parameter to the mobile site but I now want `evanstoddard.me/mobile/about` to run `evanstoddard.me/mobile.php?cmd=about`.

Here is my .htaccess file as of now:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/.]+)/?$ [NC]

RewriteRule . /index.php?cmd=%1 [L]
```

How would I go about first making `evanstoddard.me/mobile` go to `evanstoddard.me/mobile.php` and anything like `evanstoddard.me/mobile/about` point to `evanstoddard.me/mobile.php?cmd=about`?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^mobile/?$ /mobile.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^mobile/([^/.]+)/?$ /mobile.php?cmd=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?cmd=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Now I have a problem.  It redirects to the mobile page but if I try to add any parameters like `evanstoddard.me/mobile/about` then it tries to look for an about directory in a mobile directory

Comment: It's not all that big of a deal I guess because I can still do `evanstoddard.me/mobile?cmd=about` and it automatically runs that command and redirects to mobile if I run `evanstoddard.me/about`